# The field is not available for search in zoho cdk

Tags: php, zoho

I am working on Zoho PHP SDK. I want to get record of invoice but it throws error, the field is not available for search. My code is as following

```
$moduleIns = ZCRMRestClient::getInstance()->getModuleInstance("invoices");
$criteria="Invoice_Name:equals:".$orderID."";
```

This did not work. If I change above code to

```
$moduleIns = ZCRMRestClient::getInstance()->getModuleInstance("Sales_Orders");
```

If use sales orders module, then API works and returns data only for order tracking Ids but data of invoice is not coming from API. Can someone help where need to make change to make it working.
Thanks

Comment: The API module name is't correct, it's "Invoices". You can check the API modules name in Setup->Developer Space->APIs->API names

Comment: I am using "invoices" but it doesn't working. tried with "Invoices" but no result